# Connect to node.js after installing MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

When I type `var mysql=require('mysql');`, I get an error that mysql module is not found.

In which folder of node.js should MySQL be placed? Should the entire MySQL folder be placed?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what mysql folder you are talking about but I would recommend just using [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) for this and letting it handle the installation of the package.

Simply go into the folder of your project and install the MySQL Module using `npm install mysql`.

You can read more about using and installing the MySQL Module [here](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp).

Comment: When i put npm install mysql, few packages get added but in nodejs when u type "var mysql =require('mysql');" ,i get an error that the module isn't found. what do u think is the mistake? By folder i meant the node js folder which contains node_modules and all.